# Overflow of Items inside box component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, overflow

I'm planning to have a box component. There are some flex items inside it. I'm unable to accommodate all the items in the box. When I reduce width, the box width remains constant and other components overflow. How can I avoid this and fix my code?

Here is the link to my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wildflower-l4t9h?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to use flex wrap if you want to contain it into the flex-box

```
style={{
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap:"wrap",
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: "thick",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    margin: "1%"
  }}
```

Comment: flexwrap works. Is it possible to wrap everything without increasing the height of the box and dynamically increase width of the box instead?

Comment: The box is actually responsive but since you have fixed width and height for your images that is causing the responsiveness issue

Comment: Yes, but I want that instead of increasing height of the box, increase the width of the box and accommodate all elements

Comment: Thats what I am saying that width of the box is increasing  to full extent but the width of the images is more than the box